# Java - how can I obtain a K-hour-shifted TimeZone?

Tags: java, android, timezone, utc, gmt

I have a TimeZone variable (DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE) obtained by following code

```
TimeZone DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
```

And now I want to get another TimeZone that is shifted K hours from DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE.

How can I do that?

Comment: A specific `TimeZone` you can get as `TimeZone tzCET = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET");`

Answer (score 1):

If you *actually* mean "a time zone which has a permanent constant offset from UTC", that's easy:

```
int offsetMillis = (int) TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(offsetHours);
TimeZone zone = new SimpleTimeZone(offsetMillis, "some id");
```

If you mean a time zone which obeys the same daylight saving rules as another time zone, but is shifted by a fixed offset, that would be a bit harder - but also less useful, I'd argue.

Note that if you use [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time), you can achieve the former with:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(offsetHours);
```

(And you'll have a far nicer API to work with, too...)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have another question, how can I get the hour difference between 2 TimeZones?

Comment: @Season: I suggest you ask a new question for that, with a lot more detail - it really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Season - keep in mind that without a specific date and time, you *can't* always get the difference between two time zones.